# Network Drives reappearing over and over

Tags: networking, drive, reconnect

At the beginning we use a Startup-scipt to map 3 Network-Drives: M,Q,S using `net use`. (Unknown, if `/persist` has been used)

Later, the logon script has been removed, the mapping has been relocated to a GPO, using the smae letters. (Unknown, if `Reconnect` was used)

Now, this GPO has been deleted as well - because the Access-Policies for These drives has changed, so lesser user have Access. Therefore, the drives have been relocated to other letters.

The drives still coming up (inaccessible) for a lot users with the letters M,Q,S...

Even if we manually disconnect the drives, delete the entries stored in the Registry (`MountPoints2`) - after another Login, they are mapped again.

Login-Script and Prior GPO are removed - 100% sure, GPO Update was forced, and the Change was introduced weeks ago...

Any Idea what could be the cause for this?

---

We also tried the frequently recommended way to : Disconnect, Map again (NO Reconnect Option), Disconnect again. Comes up after Login again.

Answer (score 1):

You should reconfigure the GPP settings, apply the GPO to the affected users (link the GPO to the appropriate OU or target it to a specific user group) and use the Delete action.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770902.aspx

Next time you use GPP you should enable the option `Remove this item when it is no longer applied`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772371.aspx#BKMK_Remove